# Installing gfortran on PGI in Windows

Tags: windows, fortran, gfortran, pgi-visual-fortran

I am trying to get into learning Fortran for research and choosing to use PGI community edition 2015. I have installed the necessary Visual studios/other packages so the compiler works. Since PGI uses some Cygwin components, how do I download the following packages so that I may install it into the PGI compiler?
Say:

https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/mingw64-i686-gcc-fortran/?C=D;O=A

https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/make/

I do not know the correct terminology, but how would I use these file and import them into the compiler (using the "make" command). Can you also provide sample code as to how to do this setup as when I do gfortran --version, nothing is detected.

Comment: Is there an easier way for me to use fortran via PGI? If so please tell me what I should do.

Comment: Make sure you are using relevant tags so that people see your question.

Comment: I do not understand your problem at all. What is your probem with PGI? If you want PGI, don't install gfortran Describe your original problem.

Comment: No I mean to say how do I install gfortran for compatible use in the PGI compiler environment for Windows. I'm supposed to install the above packages into Cygwin (or PGI) in order to run gfortran and use that format. However, I am not sure how to download these packages and install them into the PGI compiler

Comment: If PGI is compatible with MSVC libraries, it won't be link compatible with gfortran (unless possibly you have the Lahey gfortran).  What I've seen the PGI installation do with cygwin is to set up a bash prompt so that you could use cygwin make etc. conveniently, but you would be keeping program builds separate.

Comment: You cannot instal any program into the PGI compiler. Your words do not make sense to me. Sorry. And I am trying to think what you might mean, but I don't understand your words.

Comment: It is alright I will try my best to figure this out. Thank you.